# Finding the middle of an array without knowing the length

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string

> Find the middle of the string or array with an unknown length. You may
>   not traverse the list to find the length. You may not use anything to
>   help you find the length - as it is "unknown." (ie. no sizeof (C) or count(C#) etc...)

I had this question as an interview question. I'm just wondering what the answer is. I did ask if i could use sizeof, he said "no, the size of the string or array is unknown - you just need to get to the middle."

BTW, i'm not sure if this is actually possible to solve with no traversing. I almost felt as though he may have wanted to see how confident i am in my answer :S not sure...

His English was bad - also not sure if this contributed to misunderstandings. He directly told me that i do not need to traverse the list to get to the middle :S :S I'm assuming he meant no traversing at all..... :S

Comment: This is not possible, unless you can "seek" to the end maybe.

Comment: You variously describe the data structure as "string," "array," and "list." What precisely is the thing, and what operations are valid on it?

Comment: Several people interviewing for the same position this week? I'm certain that this came up a couple days ago but I can't find the first one.

Comment: @Rob he said either string or an array - he wouldn't specify which one! A little bit annoying

Comment: @ mu is too short lol possible i guess

Comment: Middle of array or string is `r` :)

Comment: If all you know is the start of the segment, there's no way to find the middle. Imagine you stand in an open field and I tell you to go half-way in a certain direction; what are you supposed to do? The open field in this case the computer memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have two counters, c1 and c2.  Begin traversing the list, incrementing c1 every time and c2 every other time.  By the time c1 gets to the end, c2 will be in the middle.

You haven't "traversed the list to find the length" and then divided it by two, you've just gone through once.

The only other way I can think of would be to keep taking off the first and last item of the list until you are left with the one(s) in the middle.

Comment: OP mentions that you cannot traverse. Though your answer seems the one I would regard as correct.

Comment: This is a little modified version of `Hare and the Tortoise Algorithm`.

Comment: @Nick in your answer isn't c2  "traversing the list to find its length"?  Seems to me that at best it a semantic difference (not like you took it down from an O(n)..

Comment: It says "may not traverse to find the length", but I'm wondering if that wording is permitting this solution because you're not actually *explicitly* finding the length.

Comment: @Als Yes it is, you can modify the speed at which c2 increments to find 1/3, 1/4, 2/3 etc.

Comment: @awoodland That's how I see it. The obvious solution is to traverse it and find the length, then calculate from there. I think the question simply wants you to think a bit more outside the box.

Comment: @Nick your answer makes a lot of sense... i wonder if he would have accepted it... Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @BlueButtons Added an alternative to my answer.

Comment: @Als I agree, but in H&T you are providing an O(n) solution to what most people's knee-jerk O(n^2) solution.  Here the algorithmic  benefit of the question seems much less obvious...

Comment: Note that this is impossible to do with an array in C, as you do not know when to stop, (unless the array is known to be a string or other wise have a senitel value). Even in C#, you would have to rely on an exception been thrown to find the end, since the .Count/.Size property is off-limits (or perhaps you could get away with using foreach)

Comment: Hmmm yea, i had mentioned something similar during the interview but then he told me "you don't know the end of the string/array so you can't have a pointer pointing to the end of it"

Comment: @nos Exactly what i was thinking. I asked him what language this question is specific to but he told me that i could do it in any language :S

Comment: @Nick  Your alternative answer is what I though of first - but how can you traverse from the end of an array without knowing it's size (you could if it was a doubly linked list)

Comment: @nhed and @BlueButtons If you can use any language, you could use the Haskell functions `head` and `head (reverse tail)` to get the first and last items.

Comment: @Nick i suppose.. the position i was applying for required knowledge in C# as that's what they were using. On my resume i stated that i knew C++ and C as well as C# .. so i'm assuming he meant in any of those three? Not all that sure to be honest ... his English was very poor

Comment: @Nick i like your answer though. The first part.

Comment: @BlueButtons Well technically it's all compiled down to machine code anyway, so what you can do in one language, you can do in another.  But I think this goes beyond the scope of the question! He was probably just looking for the theory or, at the most, pseudo-code.

Comment: It is possible to find the length of an array by checking the address after it, see my answer, hopefully it's not too evil, but it works :)

Answer (score 5):

1. You (or your interviewer) are very vague in what the data is (you mentioned "string" and "array"); there's no assumption that can be made, so it can be anything.
2. You mentioned that the length of the string is unknown, but from your wording it might seem like you (or the interviewer) actually meant to say unknowable.

   a) If it's just unknown, then the question is, how can it can be determined? In the case of strings, for example, you can consider the end to be `'\0'`. You can then apply some algorithms like the ones suggested by the other answers.

   b) If it's unknowable, the riddle has no solution. The concept of middle has no meaning without a beginning and an end.

Bottom line, you cannot talk about a middle without a beginning and an end, or a length. Either this question was intentionally unanswerable, or you did not understand it properly. You must know more than just the beginning of the memory segment and maybe its type.

Comment: +1 to counter downvote without justification (not that the answer is not good, but i've only one vote to give).

Comment: Technically it is **impossible** for a program 'not to know' the size of an array, and the whole purpose of a string or list is walking it. The only good answer is: the question is wrong. The interviewer should have failed the interview.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will find the middle of an array WITHOUT traversing the list

```
int thearray[80];
int start = (int)&thearray;
int end = (int)(&thearray+1);
int half = ((end-start) / 4)/ 2;
std::cout <<  half << std::endl;
```

---

EDITS:

This code assumes you are dealing with an actual array and not a pointer to the first element of one, thus code like:
`int *pointer_to_first_element = (int *)malloc(someamount);`
will not work, likewise with any other notation that degrades the array reference into a pointer to the first element. Basically any notation using the `*`.

Comment: If `thearray` is an actual array of objects of size 4, rather than a pointer to the first element of one, this would work.

Comment: I initialised `thearray` as `thearray[80]` and got the result 40, You are however correct about the pointer to the first element of one, but this is the only usable method that will adhere to the 'no traversing' rule, and `sizeof(int)` can be arbitrary since it's just a hard coded number.

Comment: You sure? http://codepad.org/pWRYSkw8 BTW, if typeof(thearray) is char* then end - start = 1

Comment: that's a char pointer, this has been made for an int array, Ah I see I didn't paste the first line of code, probably would have cleared a few things up. Yes in that case it would be silly to divide by 4, but this isn't a very general question to begin with, so a very specialised answer would have to be used, for example, the OP stated array, not pointer to memory, and ints are quite standard so I used an int array.

Comment: @BlackBear: Your `thearray` is not an array, it is a pointer to the first element of an array. The size of the elements is also not 4.  With a few tweaks, this is a perfectly reasonable solution to a specific instance of this problem. http://codepad.org/D882UvEx However, at that point, you might as well just `return N/2;` and save yourself the hassle.

Comment: Don't convert pointers to integers to do arithmetic on them.  `int *start = thearray; int *end = thearray + sizeof thearray / sizeof *thearray; int *half = start + (end - start)/2;` (untested)  Of course this assumes you can determine the size (and therefore the length) of `thearray`, which contradicts the stated requirements.

Comment: @Serdalis: ah yes, now it makes much more sense ;) nice trick BTW :)

Comment: @keith I'm converting references to integers and performing no arithmatic on them, only the resulting integers, `&thearray` will be a reference to the beginning address of memory for the array, `&thearray+1` will be a reference to the first address after that array, I do realise this is a very special case but it is a case and the only one that will conform to all the rules.

Comment: @Serdalis: Your `start` and `end` are both integers, converted from pointer values (note: pointers, not references).  There is no guarantee that the result of the conversion is meaningful.  And yes, you do perform arithmetic on them: `end - start`.

Comment: @Keith I see what you're saying, you are correct, this code makes many assumptions and assumes a perfect environment. I haven't the knowledge to know when this will fail apart from the obvious cases.

Comment: @Serdalis: Suppose `int` is 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits (quite common on 64-bit systems).  Then the pointer-to-int conversions will lose information.  And apart from that, converting pointers to integers and performing arithmetic on the integers is rarely necessary; we can do (restricted) arithmetic on the pointers themselves.

Comment: @keith Thanks for the info, I'll admit I thought when going to 64bit integers would scale too (64bit), I'll read up on this some more, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would just use the difference between the addresses of the first and last elements.

Comment: How would you know the address of the last element?

Comment: @nhed after some digging, i *now* see that restriction was added to the interviewer's question after the fact, and that was point was made among twenty comments in another answer. it's also tagged c++; c++ types have methods and iterators which can be used to get addresses of front and back elements. nevertheless, it's still superior to traversal, and fits the requirements more closely than the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @anonymous_downvoter that doesn't help, unless you justify your action.

Comment: I disagree ... the fact that there are types that can report their size is irrelevant, if you use that feature you ignore the requirement of the question.  I did not like the accepted answer either (didn't downvote anything though), I think that there is something wrong in the wording of the question, it was probably attempting to simplify the T&H problem but messed it up.  I like Paul's answer the best

Comment: @nhed *the fact that there are types that can report their size is irrelevant, if you use that feature you ignore the requirement of the question.* the dominant c++stdlib class representation for an array is `std::vector`; we'll use that for demonstrations. my answer *and* my extended solution (using c++ containers) does not depend on `std::vector::size()`. (cont)

Comment: (cont) as well, the c++stdlib implementation that i use more than any other implementation does not even require the use of `std::vector::size()` *internally* when determining `front()`/`back()` or when creating iterators; the solution i provided is in essence a reimplementation of `std::vector::size()`. thus, the requirements are satisfied because the size facilities are not used. for your reference, this is the definition of gnu's `std::vector::size()`: `size_type size() const { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start); }`. (cont)

Comment: (cont) of course, the technique can also be applied to c arrays when the first and last elements are known. i don't feel my answer is incorrect *because i failed to locate all easter-egg requirements* -- that would be silly. moving along: T&H is an inferior solution in this case because it 1) also depends on knowing the last element and 2) uses traversal to determine the middle. the former is an easter-egg requirement (again, no sympathy). the latter is computationally inferior to my solution and debatably fails to meet another formal requirement (no traversal). (cont)

Comment: (cont) all things considered, my answer still holds as a good solution *at the time it was made*. the question was flawed from the start: is it a string? is it an array? is it a list? if it were a string, what would its encoding be? if that encoding is not self synchronizing... > < one could not safely assume it is even a single element when it is not null. one may as well respond only with riddles. (cont)

Comment: (cont)  yup, Paul's answer is more correct than mine; it summarizes assumptions we might usually make, accounts for easter egg requirements, and points out that it is not worded well or well understood. if i had another vote to give to his answer for that reason, i would. i don't think my answer is bad, considering the order of events and the context. in that regard, it was also an improvement over the accepted and popular answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think this problem is aimed to also test your skills in problem analysis and requirements gathering. As others have stated before, we will need at least another piece of data to solve this issue.

My approach is to let clear to the interviewer that we can solve the problem with one constraint in the function call: the caller must provide 2 pointer, one to the beginning and another to the end of the array. Given those 2 pointers, and using basic pointer arithmetic, I reach this solution; please let me know what you think about it.

```
int *findMiddleArray( int const *first, int const *last )
{
  if( first == NULL || last == NULL || first > last )
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  if( first == last )
  {
    return (int *)first;
  }
  size_t dataSize= ( size_t )( first + 1 ) - ( size_t )first,
         addFirst= ( size_t )first,
         addLast=  ( size_t )last,
         arrayLen= ( addLast - addFirst) / dataSize + 1,
         arrayMiddle= arrayLen % 2 > 0 ?  arrayLen / 2 + 1 : arrayLen / 2;

  return ( int * )( ( arrayMiddle - 1 ) * dataSize + addFirst );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

one way you can find midpoint of array is (for odd length array)
just use two loops ,1st loop start traverse from 0 index and the other (nested) loop will traverse from last index of array. Now just compare elements when it comes same ...that will be the mid point of array. i.e if(arr[i]== arr[j]) . Hope you got the point !

For Even length array ..you can do if(arr[i] == arr[j-1]) Or if(arr[i] == arr[j+1]) as they will never be same .try it by dry run!

Comment: This only works if all the array values are **unique**. For example, the loops stop immediately if the first and last elements have the same value.

Comment: The question states that the length of the array is unknown, so you can't just use the last index of the array, since that is not known.